# filtering a number from user input and using it in the program

Tags: python-3.x

I'm relatively new to python and am trying to make a digital dice, that is run by commands the user can put in. I am trying to let the user change the amount of sides the dice has by using the command "dicesides [x]" where [x] gets replaced by the amount of sides the user wants the dice to have. The input of commands gets aquired by "Input = input()", and what should happen for every command is controlled by if-statements like "if(Input == "command"): [things that should happen]" I don't know however, how I should get this to work with the command I'd like to implement, as "if(Input == "command") wouldn't work if the command is variable.

Here is my code so far, in case that helps:

```
from random import randint
dicesides = 6

print("Welcome to the dice, a command based number generator for you to use. Use \"help\" or \"h\" for help using the commands")

while(True):
  Input = input()
  if(Input == "help" or Input == "Help" or Input == "h" or Input == "H"):
    print("List of commands: ")
    print("roll - Rolls the dice")
    print("dicesides [x] - Sets the amount of sides the dice has to the value of x")
  elif(Input == "roll" or Input == "Roll"):
    value = randint(1, dicesides)
    print("The dice rolled " + str(value))
  elif(Input == dicesides):
    #change "dicesides" to the number listed in the command


    
  else:
    print("Unknown command, use \"help\" for a list of commands")
```

Does anyone have an idea as to how I would be able to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You could break it down into two commands. So first you ask for dicesides and then you write the number of sides. Something like this:

```
elif (Input == dicesides):
    dicesides = input()
```

Comment: yeah, I guess that does make sense. it'd be cool to have it in one, but this works as well I guess.

Thank you!